# About binary quadratic forms

Tags: number-theory

How many $\operatorname{GL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$-equivalence classes of integral binary quadratic forms of discriminant $-4$ are there? For example, the equivalence class of $x^2+y^2$ is one, what are the others?

Comment: That's it!${{}}$

Comment: Why? Would you please explain.

Comment: @sal It follows from the reduction theory of binary quadratic forms. See Gauss's *Disquisitiones Arithmeticae* or any number of modern textbooks.

Comment: So it is not an easy to prove result?

Comment: Start searching yourself! If you need a reference, here is a [handout](http://math.uga.edu/~pete/8430notes3.pdf) by Pete Clark.